# CSS element not aligning properly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align my logo at the very left of the screen. I want to keep all of my other elements at the location on the screen. Every time I try to edit the margin or padding of my logo, all of my elements pile up. I know this seems like a pretty easy question, but I just can't figure this out. My code is down bellow.

```css
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  #header{
  
  padding-left: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  }
  
  #header #logo{
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  #header #logo span{
  color: #1566e0;
  }
  #header nav{
  color: #1566e0;
  }
  
  #header nav a{
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  }
  
  #header nav a:hover{
  opacity: 0.9;
  }


  #header nav a:last-child{
    color: white;
    background: #1566e0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    }
    #container{
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      padding-top: 20px;
      height: 575px;
      }
      #bg-container{
      width: 50%;
      }
      #bg-container svg{
      width: 100%;
      height: 90%;
      }
      #content-container{
      width: 30%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      }
      #content-container h1 {
      color: #1566e0 !important;
      font-weight: 900;
      font-size: 80px;
      line-height: 0.9em;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      }
      #content-container p{
      line-height: 1.8em;
      font-weight: 500;
      }
      #content-container button{
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: #FFF;
      background-color: #1566e0;
      padding: 16px 0px;
      border-radius: 40px;
      font-size: 16px;
      width: 160px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      }
      #content-container button:hover{
      opacity: 0.9;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>GoodDeed - Home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
      <style>
          @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500;600;700');
      </style>
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500;600;700" rel="stylesheet">
    
    
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <div id="logo">
            <h3><span>Good</span>Deed</h3>
         </div>
         <nav>
            <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
            <a href="#">INFO</a>
            <a href="#">DASHBOARD</a>
            <a href="#">GET STARTED</a>
         </nav>
      </div>
      <div id="container">
        <div id="content-container">
           <h1>Welcome!</h1>
           <p>Eradicating malnorisment and poverty by connecting people in need and donors. 
              To learn how you can help make a difference,
              click here!</p>
           <button>Read More</button>
        </div>
        <div id="bg-container">
        </div>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `padding-left:20%` of header element and the following style to to #header

```
#header{
 
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between; /* changes here */
  align-items: center;
  }
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  #header{
  
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between; /* changes here */
  align-items: center;
  }
  
  #header #logo{
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  #header #logo span{
  color: #1566e0;
  }
  #header nav{
  color: #1566e0;
  }
  
  #header nav a{
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  }
  
  #header nav a:hover{
  opacity: 0.9;
  }


  #header nav a:last-child{
    color: white;
    background: #1566e0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    }
    #container{
      overflow: hidden;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      padding-top: 20px;
      height: 575px;
      }
      #bg-container{
      width: 50%;
      }
      #bg-container svg{
      width: 100%;
      height: 90%;
      }
      #content-container{
      width: 30%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      }
      #content-container h1 {
      color: #1566e0 !important;
      font-weight: 900;
      font-size: 80px;
      line-height: 0.9em;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      }
      #content-container p{
      line-height: 1.8em;
      font-weight: 500;
      }
      #content-container button{
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: #FFF;
      background-color: #1566e0;
      padding: 16px 0px;
      border-radius: 40px;
      font-size: 16px;
      width: 160px;
      margin-top: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      }
      #content-container button:hover{
      opacity: 0.9;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>GoodDeed - Home</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
      <style>
          @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500;600;700');
      </style>
         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500;600;700" rel="stylesheet">
    
    
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <div id="logo">
            <h3><span>Good</span>Deed</h3>
         </div>
         <nav>
            <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
            <a href="#">INFO</a>
            <a href="#">DASHBOARD</a>
            <a href="#">GET STARTED</a>
         </nav>
      </div>
      <div id="container">
        <div id="content-container">
           <h1>Welcome!</h1>
           <p>Eradicating malnorisment and poverty by connecting people in need and donors. 
              To learn how you can help make a difference,
              click here!</p>
           <button>Read More</button>
        </div>
        <div id="bg-container">
        </div>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did that, and it does not work. I ran your code snippet and it works in  that. Do you know why it is not working in my program?

Comment: @user10793022 did you add the `justify-content: space-between; ` to header

Comment: No, I copied the code you gave me. Your answer did not say anything about justify content.

Comment: Can you please update your code so I can copy it?

Comment: @user10793022 please share the latest code that you are using now

Comment: @xxxbabyslayerxxx is there any other CSS style you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232889/discussion-between-deepu-reghunath-and-xxxbabyslayerxxx).